# JQuery UI Datepicker IE position issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am having a problem with the jQuery UI datepicker in IE.

When I have a short page and the datepickers are at the bottom, if the user selects the date its position is under the text element. In IE it is not letting them scroll down at this point and because of this they are unable to select any dates in IE. I have checked this in other browsers and its position in Firefox, Chrome, Opera, and Safari is above the element.

Why will it not behave the same in IE as the other browsers I've checked?

Answer (score 0):

I know that it's not the answer but it might lead you to it. Check if the vertical scrollbar is shown when you click on the input. You might be able to scroll down using your mouse wheel.

You also can consider asking your clients to move on to a better browser.

IE is losing fans every month. Check the browser statistics-
http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp